# Picture not showing up in production build but shows up in dev

Tags: html, css, reactjs, image

I ran into a problem yesterday. Never experienced it before. The images are not loading correctly in the production build, but when I check in dev build the images loads perfectly fine. Tried different solutions around the web. Double checking paths, using require instead of import, but no luck.

Hope someone on here can point me in the right direction.

Image of the page:
[image: page]

```
import React from 'react'
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap'
import NavbarComponent from '../components/navbar/Navbar' 
import Footer from '../components/footer/Footer'
import Seatmap from '../components/seatmap/Seatmap'
import '../css/SeatMap.css'

function SeatMap() {
  return (
    <Container fluid className="seatmap d-flex flex-column m-0 p-0">
        <NavbarComponent data={{ background: 'transparent' }} />
        <Container fluid className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center p-0 m-0 mb-5">
          <div className="bg-light w-25 mx-auto d-flex mb-5" style={{ height: '15vh' }}>
            <h3 className="fw-bolder text-center m-auto">SCENE</h3>
          </div>
          <Seatmap />
        </Container>
        <Footer />
    </Container>
  )
}

export default SeatMap
```

```
import React from 'react'
import './Navbar.css'
import { Nav, Navbar, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap'
import logo from '../logo.png'

function NavbarComponent(props) {
  return (
    <>
        <Navbar expand='md' collapseOnSelect bg={props.data.background} variant='dark'>
            <Navbar.Brand style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-start', width: '25%', marginLeft: '2.5%', alignItems: 'center' }} href='/'>
                <img
                    src={require('../logo.png')}
                    alt='KvammaLAN'
                    style={{
                        objectFit: 'contain',
                        width: '50%',
                        height: 'auto',
                    }}
                />
            </Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle style={{ marginRight: '2.5%' }} aria-controls='responsive-navbar-nav' />
            <Navbar.Collapse id='responsive-navbar-nav'>
                <Nav>
                    <Nav.Link className="mx-4" href='/'>HEIM</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link className="mx-4" href='/om-oss'>OM OSS</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link className="mx-4" href='/kvammalan'>KVAMMALAN 2023</Nav.Link>
                    <NavDropdown className="mx-4" title='HJELP' menuVariant='dark'>
                        <NavDropdown.Item href='/faq'>OFTE STILTE SPØRSMÅL</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Item href='/kontakt-oss'>KONTAKT OSS</NavDropdown.Item>
                    </NavDropdown>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    </>
  )
}

export default NavbarComponent
```